# Prove torus is homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1$

Tags: general-topology

The coordinates of torus is $((R+r\cos \theta)\cos \phi,(R+r\cos \theta)\sin \phi,r\sin \phi)$

So I let $g:[0,2 \pi] \times [0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$
by $g(\theta, \phi)=(e^{i\theta},e^{i\phi})$

Then I prove that this function is continuous, bijection and open mapping. Bijection is quite obvious, but how to prove continuous and open mapping?

The open set in $[0,2 \pi] \times [0,2 \pi]$ is a square without boundary (not sure if it is right) , but what is the open set in $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ ?

Also if we take an open set in $[0,2 \pi] \times [0,2 \pi]$, say $U$ and act $ g $ on it to be $g(U)$, what will it look like?

Thank you!

Comment: I think in order to make your map $g$ injective you need to restrict the domain to $[0,2 \pi) \times [0, 2 \pi).$ Because at $0$ and $2 \pi$ we get the same point on the circle. But if it's a homeomorphism that forces the semi-open and semi-closed square to be compact since so is $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1.$ How can that be possible either? The said square is bounded but not closed and hence can't be compact. I am confused at this stage.

Comment: So according to my intuition the inverse of $g$ can't be continuous because in order to get the inverse you need complex logarithm to come into the picture but complex logarithm is also continuous (and holomorphic) only when you take branch cut (any half ray through the origin) and any such branch cut intersects the circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think about the map in the opposite way:

When you said that the coordinates of the torus are $$((R+r\cos \theta)\cos \phi,(R+r\cos \theta)\sin \phi,r\sin \phi)$$ you were providing a global parametrization of the torus.
This is a map $$f(\theta, \phi) = (x(\theta, \phi), y(\theta, \phi), z(\theta, \phi))$$

With $x(\theta, \phi) = (R+r\cos \theta)\cos \phi$, etc. etc...

**Each of the coordinate maps $x,y,z$ is continuous because they simply inherit continuity from the elementary trigonometric functions** (finite products and sums of continuous functions are continuous), so the parametrization $f(\theta, \phi)$ is continuous.  $f$ is also clearly bijective, as you noted.

Now all you need to show is that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  Equivalently, you said, you could show that $f$ is an open map.  Or, better yet, **since $f$ is a bijection, it's being an open map is equivalent to being a closed map**.

Let's abstract for a moment.  If you have any continuous $f: X \rightarrow Y$ with $X$ compact and $Y$ a $KC$-space (compact subsets of $Y$ are closed), then you have that $f$ is a closed map.  This is very general and very important! Closed subsets of compact spaces are compact, and compactness is invariant under continuous maps.  If compactness implies closedness in $Y$, then $f$ maps closed subsets of $X$ to closed subsets of $Y$ just because it's continuous.  So, a **function $f$ on a compact space is a homeomorphism iff it is bijective and continuous** (so long as $Y$ has a bit of structure).

Now in your case $Y$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$, in which compact is equivalent to closed and bounded, so certainly $Y$ is a $KC$-space.  Meanwhile recall that $S^1$ is compact and therefore $S^1 \times S^1$ is compact space since the product of two compact spaces is compact.  So, having already seen that $f$ is a continuous bijection, $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism.